# Spatialite cocoapod doesn't install correclty

Tags: sqlite, cocoapods, spatialite

I've made new Xcode project with a template.
I have a pod file that only asks for the 'spatialite/core' pod (which is dependent on the sqlite3 pod.
I run 'pod install --verbose', and I get this:

```
Analyzing dependencies

Updating spec repositories
Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  Already up-to-date.

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - spatialite/core

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
Starting resolution (2015-04-04 23:47:58 -0700)
Creating possibility state for spatialite/core (= 4.1.1) (1 remaining)
  Attempting to activate spatialite/core (4.1.1)
  Activated spatialite/core at spatialite/core (4.1.1)
  Requiring nested dependencies (sqlite3)
  Creating possibility state for sqlite3 (1 remaining)
    Attempting to activate sqlite3 (3.8.8.3)
    Activated sqlite3 at sqlite3 (3.8.8.3)
    Requiring nested dependencies (sqlite3/common (= 3.8.8.3))
    Creating possibility state for sqlite3/common (= 3.8.8.3) (1 remaining)
      Attempting to activate sqlite3/common (3.8.8.3)
      Activated sqlite3/common at sqlite3/common (3.8.8.3)
      Requiring nested dependencies ()
Finished resolution (3 steps) (Took 0.007224 seconds) (2015-04-04 23:47:58 -0700)
Unactivated:
Activated: spatialite/core, sqlite3, sqlite3/common

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  - spatialite
  - sqlite3

Downloading dependencies

-> Using spatialite (4.1.1)

-> Using sqlite3 (3.8.8.3)
  - Running pre install hooks

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `Pods-sqlite3` iOS 8.0
    - Installing target `Pods` iOS 8.0
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
  - Writing Lockfile in `Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in `Pods/Manifest.lock`

Integrating client project

Integrating target `Pods` (`TestProject.xcodeproj` project)
```

Everything processed without error, but the problem is that it only installs Pod-sqlite3 and Pod, but not Pod-spatialite.

I've been looking at the podspec.json file, but I can't see anything wrong, and I can't find ways to debug this any further. It would be very helpful if somebody could point me to command line options for the 'pod' command that give the core details about what it is executing in the background, and where it goes wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it doesn't get added: the code gets downloaded correctly, but the podspec.json is configured incorrectly which results in the downloaded code not being found.

The solution is to change the podspec.json file as follows:

```
   "source": {
-    "http": "http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/libspatialite-4.1.1.tar.gz"
+    "http": "http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/libspatialite-4.1.1.tar.gz",
+    "flatten": true
   },
```

After this, things start working. It still fails compilation later, but that's due to another, known issue (see https://github.com/andreacremaschi/SpatialDBKit and https://github.com/andreacremaschi/SpatialDBKit/issues/12)